# Problem when scrolling on mobile menu on several browsers

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

i have problem when scrolling on mobile menu with several browser, at my default browser on android and safari browser on IOS, which is when you open the mobile menu and you scroll to the bottom, it seems it will follow to scrolled too with the page behind the menu, so it seems like not fixed/stay
but when i try on desktop with mobile view, and also using chrome and others on my phone it will fixed and stay. maybe you can help me with inspect element to look at code, if there is something i need to fix
the website is here: http://enerdoverdose18.staging.lipsiaserver.com/it

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to body css when the menu is open so the page behind will not move

```
   position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
```